# increment/decrement .data() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dom elements seems a perfect place to attach data that relates to that element, but accessing it is cumbersome code-wise, and probably inefficient too.

Currently I am doing something like this to increment:

```
$('#the-thing').data({ counter: $('#the-thing').data('counter') + 1 })
```

Is there a faster way to increment a number stored in the .data() of a jQuery object?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Better:

```
var data = $('#the-thing').data();
data.counter += 1;
// `$('#the-thing').data().counter += 1` should work too
```

This avoids calling the data method twice. The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/) also says:

> Using the object directly to get or set values is faster than making individual calls to .data() to get or set each value.

---

<s>You could create a function if you really wanted to:</s>

```
function add(sel, prop, val) {
    var data = $(sel).data();
    data[prop] += val;
}
```

As @Zirak points out, if you make this calls regularly, a plugin might be the best choice:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.inc = function(prop, val) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var data = $(this).data();
            if(!(prop in data)) {
                data[prop] = 0;
            }
            data[prop] += val;
        });
    }
}(jQuery))
```

which can be used with:

```
$('#the-thing').inc('counter', 1);
$('#the-thing').inc('counter', -1);
```

I know `inc` is not a good method name as it suggests that you can only *increase* the value. But I could not think of something better.... I'm open for suggestions :)

Comment: As an off-note, making a jQuery plugin would be better I think, so you could chain and use it right along with your already-selected elements. Of course, only if you want to use it multiple times and am feeling comfortable with it.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/cwolves/DYWkh/4/ -- I'm overwriting .data(), but this could be easily just be named something else